# how to fix lock_wait_time_out errors?

Tags: mysql

we are getting lock_wait_time_out errors fequently in slaves due to this replication got broken.at that time we are starting slave sql thread manually.

how to fix this permanently.

**Error:**

```
Slave SQL: Error 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' on query. Default database:
```

Comment: From what I can tell online, this is typically caused by badly written queries.  It looks like diagnosis usually starts with `show innodb status` but that's over my head.